# How to find '>' and wrap into a <span> tag without nesting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to find `>` sign in editable `div` with `REGEX`, replace it wrapping in span. The script(`REGEX`) works, but it has a few bugs.

If I type `>` sign 2 times dividing them by space like `> >`, it creates the following.

```
<span>
 <span>&gt;</span>
 &gt;
</span>
```

Instead I need this without nesting:

```
<span>&gt;</span>
<span>&gt;</span>
```

Also If I type `>` 2 times without space like `>>`, `REGEX` should take each `>` sign and wrap it into a separate `span`, like this:

```
<span>&gt;</span>
<span>&gt;</span>
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>


.editable{
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  cursor: text;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

span{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}



var createRange = function (node, chars, range) {
  if (!range) {
    range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNode(node);
    range.setStart(node, 0);
  }

  if (chars.count === 0) {
    range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
  } else if (node && chars.count >0) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      if (node.textContent.length < chars.count) {
        chars.count -= node.textContent.length;
      } else {
        range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
        chars.count = 0;
      }
    } else {
      for (var lp = 0; lp < node.childNodes.length; lp++) {
        range = createRange(node.childNodes[lp], chars, range);

        if (chars.count === 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return range;
};

var setCurrentCursorPosition = function (chars) {
  if (chars >= 0) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();

    range = createRange(document.querySelector('.editable'), { count: chars });

    if (range) {
      range.collapse(false);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }
};

$('.editable').on('keydown', function() {
  if( new RegExp(/(?!<span>)&gt;(?!<\/span)/, 'g').test($(this).html()) ) {
    $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(/(?!<span>)&gt;(?!<\/span)/g, '<span>&gt;</span>')
    );

    setCurrentCursorPosition( $(this).text().length );
  }
});
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/phpguest/pen/abNYdGw)

You can ignore `createRange`, `setCurrentCursorPosition` functions. They just move the cursor when typing `>` into the `div`.

Comment: you want to use  regex on HTML?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I do

Comment: you may want to read this first  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5053002

Comment: I saw the main answer which says don't use REGEX for parsing html, but others say if you work with small amount of data, it's ok. So this script is small one, it has a small check/REGEX. If there is &gt; not inside <span>, put it in <span>. And that's all.

Answer (score -1):

Use html entities

```html
<span>&gt;</span>
```

> Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: If you look at the script, you'll see that script is written with entities.